# How to use Transform api in gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

I am new to Gradle, I'm now trying to use AOP to design a plugin that can manipulate bytecode. And I'm now trying to use transform API， however I cannot get the correct library imported, like TransformManager, etc.

I know this question is a little dumb but I don't really know what to do with it... So for the following, I just copied and pasted the code from the source I'm learning from, but It's the same when I'm writing the code myself, I can't import the correct library, instead, the auto-import is
`import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Transform` which I didn't find in the transform api.

Can anybody explain why? and how can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: you need `gradle-api-3.0.0.jar` or similar

Comment: it sits at `<android-studio-root>/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/`

Comment: so I download it online and put it into the folder you showed? But I didn't find the folder yo usaid

Comment: are you using AS 3.* ?

Comment: yes the latest version

Comment: so whats inside `<as_root>/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/‌​build/gradle-api/` ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I didnt even find the directory，I'm using mac

Comment: see https://afterecho.uk/blog/create-a-standalone-gradle-plugin-for-android-part-4-the-transform-api.html what you probably need to change is `Step 0` - instead of `transform-api` you need the jar i mentioned - something like [this](https://afterecho.uk/blog/create-a-standalone-gradle-plugin-for-android-part-4-the-transform-api.html#comment-3021435016) comment

Answer (score 0):

Lack of dependence,add libraries into plugin_demo/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation gradleApi()
    implementation localGroovy()

    //android gradle plugin libraries
    implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'    
    implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.3.0'
}
```